# Add a floating div in a popup

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I want to some cards on the bootstrap modal form.

In modal, I want cards in two columns for that I use the class "col-md-5"

`.mycard.col-md-5
 card contents`

> But class "col-md-5" add a property **Float:left** in the cards.

Due to which It will cards were showing outside of the modal popup

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use overflow:hidden css on the div class row or parent of the col-md-5 divs it will solve the issue.

Comment: try overflow:auto or float:none in parent div

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Chilll007

adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent `div` did the job.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the floats below the 4 divs. Try this code.

```
<div class="mycard col-md-5">
content
</div>
<div class="mycard col-md-5">
content
</div>
<div class="mycard col-md-5">
content
</div>
<div class="mycard col-md-5">
content
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use clearfix to avoid showing outside of the modal popup

```
<div class="col-md-5">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

please use **clearfix** this will help you

Comment: using bootstrap clearfix will works everywhere and it reduce unnecessary css. try once it will work otherwise ignore

Answer (score 0):

use `class="row"` before col

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
</div>
```